# Preciso usar vírgula para dizer que "bebi café, de manhã"?

Tags: pontuação, vírgula

Deveríamos usar vírgula quando dizemos que "bebemos café de manhã"? Quando dizemos isso, queremos dizer que bebemos café durante o período da manhã, e não que o café pertença à manhã. Ou quer dizer que ele é da manhã, pois foi consumido na manhã?

O certo é "bebi café de manhã" ou "bebi café, de manhã"? E por que não dizemos "bebi café na manhã"? Afinal o café estava lá no período da manhã. Não estamos falando errado?

Comment: Não cabe vírgula em advérbios postos pós-oração principal. O correto é "Bebemos café de manhã" ou "Bebemos, de manhã, café" ou "De manhã, bebemos café". O "em + a = na" dá ideia de movimento, lugar ou meio de transporte, então evita-se usá-lo como em "Bebi café na manhã", "Fui na rua" etc.

Comment: Adendo: Isso quer dizer que o café foi consumido pela manhã. Acredito que para deixar claro que o café fora feito durante a manhã, poderia usar o artigo "a": *Bebemos o café da manhã*

Answer (score -2):

Primeiro: não há "café de manhã", e sim "café da manhã". Se quiser colocar "CAFÉ DE" estaria se referindo ao tipo de bebida: café de grão moído, café de filtro, café de máquina...
A vírgula vai depender apenas da forma como escreve/fala a frase:

- Pela manhã, tomei meu café às 6:00
- Tomei meu café da manhã às 6:00
  Por que na primeira frase não escrevi "café da manhã"? Porque seria redundância você dizer que pela MANHÃ tomou CAFÉ DA MANHÃ.
  Quanto a questão de horários, é mais um "ajuste" de quando comeu algo. Se disser que almoçou, já é esclarecido - pelo menos o normal - que foi à tarde e quando jantou já era mais à noite. Mas nada impede que você diga: 'tomei meu café da manhã só à tarde", por exemplo.
  Quando você pergunta "por que não café na manhã", o problema é outro: "NA" é uma preposição ("em + a") que se refere a lugar e não horários:  "pela manhã, eu tomei café NA padaria" ou "NA minha casa".
  Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Julia, "de manhã" é uma locução adverbial (Priberam) que significa "Entre o amanhecer e o meio-dia.".

Comment: Sua resposta está errada, porque não se bebe ou come "da manhã", mas sim, de manhã. Portanto, bebi café de manhã, como "bebi café à tarde", "bebi café à noite", "bebi café de madrugada".